# Will the 1TB hard drive from my Lenovo Ideapad Z585 work in another computer of a different make/model?

Tags: hard-drive, lenovo-laptop

I wiped my 1TB hard drive from my Lenovo Ideapad Z585. Can I switch it into another computer I buy, or does it only fit a Lenovo Ideapad z585?

I'm thinking about buying an alienware, but I want to know if my hard drive will work in an Alienware.

Comment: You can use it on any computer provided you have the correct mouthing bracket and remove it from the current one if there is one.

Comment: What is a mouthing bracket? And where would I get a different one?

Comment: A **mounting** bracket allows you to install a 2.5" in a 3.5" slot.  We cannot predict if it will work, but unless Alienware doesn't use the industry standard for connections, there is no reason it shouldn't work provided you use the correct connector and mounting bracket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most laptop comes with standard sized HDD which will fit in another laptop perfectly fine. There are some (physically) different HDD but a bit rare.

Also as Ramhound mentioned, when you remove the HDD from the laptop, often there is a mounting bracket, or some sort of brackets attached to the HDD. As long as you are re-using the brackets from the new laptop, and the HDD is not physically different, then you won't have any issue.

Also make sure that the HDD from the old laptop will also connect to the new one (IDE / SATA / mSATA).

Barring the "Physical" Differences between the HDD (physical size, and connector), the HDD will work in a new laptop (or desktop) perfectly fine.